# Use images in a css ruby on rails 4 error

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I want to use images from a CSS, all my images are in the folder `app/assets/imagenes` and I add in the CSS like this:

```
#punica-page-header {
  background: url(../app/assets/imagenes/dimension.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover; }
```

than I add this in the `application.html.erb`:

```
<body class="punica-home-1">
    <header id="punica-page-header">
    </header>
</body>
```

this is the error that I have every time:

> GET http://localhost:3000/app/assets/imagenes/dimension.png 404 (Not Found)        jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:3734

I really appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: Are you sure, that your folder is called "imagenes" and not "images"?

Comment: I made a mistake but thats not the error, I found a solution thanks

Comment: You should post your solution or delete your question.

Comment: Try: `background: url('/imagenes/dimension.png') no-repeat center;`

Comment: sorry it took me a couple minutes to post the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use asset pipeline. Give extension to your stylesheet file `my_file.scss.erb`
and then you can insert image like this

```
#punica-page-header {
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'dimension.png' %>)
}
```

or

```
#punica-page-header {
background: url(<%= asset_data_uri 'dimesion.png' %>)
}
```

Edit: and of course images are in `app/assets/images` :)

Answer (score 1):

If you placed your image in `app/assets/images` folder, then can simply do it like this:

```
background: url(asset-path("dimension.png")) no-repeat center;
```

Just rename your css file extension like: `filename.css.scss`

It'll also work if you upload it in Heroku. Just make sure your Turbolink is working.

Answer (score 0):

apparently I need to make it global in this way :

```
background: url("/assets/dimension.png")
```